# remove All lines except first 20 using php

Tags: php, file, truncate, lines

how to remove every line except the first 20 using php from a text file?

Comment: You should be doing some research on your own as well. This website supplements other resources and not an alternative to the rest of the internet. People would love to help, but, you have to take a few steps to help yourself also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a memory efficient solution you can use

```
$file = new SplFileObject('/path/to/file.txt', 'a+');
$file->seek(19); // zero-based, hence 19 is line 20
$file->ftruncate($file->ftell());
```

Answer (score 7):

If loading the entire file in memory is feasible you can do:

```
// read the file in an array.
$file = file($filename);

// slice first 20 elements.
$file = array_slice($file,0,20);

// write back to file after joining.
file_put_contents($filename,implode("",$file));
```

A better solution would be to use the function [**ftruncate**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php) which takes the file handle and the new size of the file in bytes as follows:

```
// open the file in read-write mode.
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r+');
if(!$handle) {
    // die here.
}

// new length of the file.
$length = 0;

// line count.
$count = 0;

// read line by line.    
while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        // increment line count.
        ++$count;

        // if count exceeds limit..break.
        if($count > 20) {
                break;
        }

        // add the current line length to final length.
        $length += strlen($buffer);
}

// truncate the file to new file length.
ftruncate($handle, $length);

// close the file.
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: wouldn't you need to know the byte count of the 20th \n then?

Comment: i'm not familiar enough with fopen(), as to whether it puts the entire file into memory as well, but if fopen() uses less memory you could use it along with fgets() for the first twenty lines

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, mis-read the question...

```
$filename = "blah.txt";
$lines = file($filename);
$data = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $data .= $lines[$i] . PHP_EOL;
}
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
```

Comment: I think this will give you a file with everything *but* the first 20 lines.  If I understand it correctly, @Ahsan wants *only* the first 20.

Comment: This looks better but you'd better make that $i < 20 or you'll read 21 lines :)  You got the right idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$lines_array = file("yourFile.txt");
$new_output = "";

for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++){
$new_output .= $lines_array[$i];
}

file_put_contents("yourFile.txt", $new_output);
```

Comment: You can use file() to read the contents into an array so you don't have to manually explode() the data.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well without huge memory usage

```
$result = '';
$file = fopen('/path/to/file.txt', 'r');
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
{
    $result .= fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', $result);
```